# Google Cloud SQL - -21472 Row cannot be located for updating

Tags: sql, sql-server, cloud, google-cloud-sql

We are in the process of moving OnPrem MSSQLServers to Google CloudSQL MSSQLServer 2017 Standard.  Out of 200 transfers so far, we came across 2 that began having issues with Update Statements. Between the 2 the same tables are not always effected.  New Records can get created but updates will fail with below error. The OnPrem instances are 2012 and 2014 MSSQL

> SQL Error on Update
> -21472 Row cannot be located for updating. Some values may have been changed since it was last read

We use ADODB Connection with ADODB Recordsets

> RecordSet.CursorLocation = adUseClient

```
Provider=MSOLEDBSQL; initial catalog= GeoLogicServer; Data Source=10.1.0.149; User ID=NOTAUser; password=NOTAPW;Persist Security Info=True
```

The only workaround we have found is to export the tables from one instance to another, in the process losing Identity and index settings.  After resetting the Identities the tables update without issue

Any recommendation on settings we can review?

We are still testing restoring to other instances and backing up from different versions of sql.  putting the backups on another on prem server still works fine

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the bad DBs were older 2012 and 2014.  Restoring to and Backing up from a 2016 MSSQL seems to have fixed the issue when then restoring to the Google 2017 SQL instance.